# how to store created/modified by --- user details in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to store values of users who are creating and editing data. How do I do that without touching session variables. I used FOSUserbundle to for user management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blameable from [Doctrine extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) will do this job.

Comment: can you give me an example how to use it out here itself. Whats the best way to do the task without the extension

Comment: Here is documentation on using doctrine extensions in symfony2 project (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html) and here is documentation on this extension itself (https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/blameable.md)